# Specifying the number of rows per page in Dompdf

Tags: yii, dompdf, yii1.x

this is my controller code for pdf view

```
define( 'DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', FALSE );
                require_once( Yii::app()->basePath . "/../vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php" );

                $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                $dompdf->set_paper( "A2", 'landscape' );

                $html = $this->render( 'register', [
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'batch' => $batch,
                        'course' => $course,
                        'pdf'   =>  $pdf
                    ], TRUE );
                 // echo $html;die();
                $dompdf->load_html( $html );
                $dompdf->render();
                $dompdf->stream( "{$course->course_name}-{$batch->batch_name}-admission_register.pdf", 
                    [ 'Attachment' => 0 ] );
```

How can i set the no of rows shown in a page?

I tried something like in this view

```
  $sl = 1;
  foreach( $dataProvider->getData() as $students )
  {
    if($sl>10)
    {
      echo "<div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>";
    }
                echo "
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{$sl}</td>
                    <td>{$students->admission_no}</td>
                    <td>{$students->Fullname}</td>
                    <td>";
                ....
    }
```

Comment: A DIV element is not valid at that point. You'll just have to add code to end the table, add the page break, and start a new table.

Comment: @BrianS thanks it worked

Comment: Great! Add a sample of your code as an answer for other people to find :)